# Visual Studio 2017 class or method comment shortcut (formerly ///)

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In previous versions of Visual Studio, when writing a class or method the user could type `///` to have the IDE provide a structured comment block. This isn't strictly a 'keyboard shortcut', nor is it a snippet.

This doesn't work in Visual Studio 2017. Is there now a new key sequence to generate that comment block? Or is it deprecated?

Comment: This wasn't working until I rebooted my PC. Using Windows 10 in 2017. Go figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature hasn't changed from VS 2015 to 2017. Typing /// should generate a XML comment. Like in VS 2015 this feature can be enabled or disabled in VS 2017. Please check if in Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced the option "Generate XML documentation for ///" is switched on.

Comment: Seems fine after I restarted twice.

Answer (score 1):

Just typing /// will do the work. For example if you type /// before the following method:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
```

the editor will append this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
```

There is a list of commands here: http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Yet the cause was that I did not note that there was a [httppsot] attribute above the place where I was trying to write the function summary. So be sure that you type /// before all function attributes.